# Overleaf - How to include word count in Chapter/Section heading?

Tags: overleaf, word-count

I'm aware that there are previous questions on this forum dealing with Word Counts, but I have a specific issue...
Overleaf has previously acknowledged how to include word counts in the main text: 
[Is there a way to run a word count that doesn't include LaTeX commands?](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Is_there_a_way_to_run_a_word_count_that_doesn%27t_include_LaTeX_commands%3F)

In summary, you declare this command that utilises write18 and texcount:

```
\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge -q #1.tex output.bbl > #1-words.sum }%
  \input{#1-words.sum} words%
}
```

And then in your code you call *\quickwordcount[filename]*

So far so good.

My question is - **how do I display the output of the *\quickwordcount[filename]* within a *\section* tag**

This is so that in the Table of Contents I can see at a glance how many words are in each chapter (I'm dealing with a large document of 80k words so need to know which chapters to prioritise in my writing).

If I try to include the command directly in the section command then Overleaf inputs the command output on a new line and generates an error about *Text capacity exceeded*

[image]

This is the code I've used. I can see that the error is to do with *\quickwordcount[filename]* introducing a new line before writing its contents, which is a violation of how Sections work. I just don't know how to do this differently. Any help appreciated!

```
\chapter{Introduction}
%\chaptermark{Introduction}
\label{chap:introduction}

\section{Overview \quickwordcount{A_Introduction/main}}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `\protect` before the `\quickwordcount`?

Comment: @LianTzeLim That worked! would you like to add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer. I did think the answer must be rather simple and to do with limiting commands that break the section environment but just didn't know what to search for!

Comment: @LianTzeLim using \protect I still get errors about hyperref on the commands for \immediate, \write \subscript etc. --  Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\immediate' on input line 11. Do i just supress these using silence?

Comment: You can do `\section[Overview]{Overview \protect\quickwordcount{...}}` so that only "Overview" is used for ToC.

Comment: Why do you need to do a word count? Publishers/printers are only concerned about the number of pages (thesis rule makers may differ but in general they don't know what they are doing). Anyway, what is a word: a hyphenated word: an illustration: a mathematical expression: titles; footnotes;...? If you are looking to trim your text start with the longest chapters/sections.

Comment: @PeterWilson Interesting philosophical questions. Bluntly put, its to gather information about how long a chapter is at a glance (reducing cognitive effort required to browse through 4 pages of ToC). Lazy? Perhaps.

Comment: Perhaps then you need a page count rather than a word count. I can't help with this but I'm sure others can. Be interesting to see if page count vs. word count give different priorities for you.